# Создание формы добавление множества записей в Django

Tags: python, django

Есть две модели:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ....

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    category = ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

я хочу, чтобы при помощи формы можно было добавить сразу несколько человек.
Попробовала так:
forms.py

```
class categoryForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = ('name',)

class personForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name',)

class personFormTwo(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name',)
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
form_category = categoryForm(request.POST)
form_person = personForm(request.POST)
form_person_two = personFormTwo(request.POST)
if form_category.is_valid() and form_person.is_valid() and form_person_two.is_valid():
    cat = form_category.save()
    catTwo = form_category.save()
    form_person.save(commit=False)
    form_person_two.save(commit=False)
    form_person.id_category = cat
    form_person_two.id_category = catTwo
    form_person.save()
    form_person_two.save()
```

html

```
<form method='POST'>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ categoryForm.as_p }}
{{ personForm.as_p }}
{{ personFormTwo.as_p }}
</form>
```

Но так, на странице появляются совершенно одинаковые две формы с одинаковыми id у input`ов, что не есть хорошо

И при `print(personForm.cleaned_data)` Выводятся пустые значения, кроме числовых полей там Null
Как реализовать?

Чтобы не плодить еще один вопрос и чтобы еще больше не испытывать стыд, Второй вопрос, если можно...

Есть модель:

```
class system(models.Model):
status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
....
```

Возможно ли изменить значение поле статуса, при сохранение формы из первого вопроса и как это сделать?

Заранее спасибо. Буду ждать подсказок

Comment: Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Сталкнулся  с подобной проблемой. Может кому поможет: https://django.fun/tutorials/dinamicheskoe-dobavlenie-form-v-django-s-pomoshyu-naborov-form-i-javascript/